# Condensation on windows

Tags: ford, heater, explorer

I'll just start with **you're going to feel like this is a vague question**

2002 ford explorer xlt 6cyl 4.0 sohc

I made a joke to my co-worker about my suv being 2 faced. It had condensation on the passenger side from the inside but not on the drivers side, This has happened many times in the past too i just didn't pay no attention to it until he said that it could be the heater core, which kind of freaked me out...

My car heats up pretty good, but from time to time it feels like it might cool down when i stop at lights, There's no coolant smell and no wet feel around the floor on the passenger side. I really hate to spend 5 - 6 hours tearing apart my dash just to find that my heater core is ok and not leaking

What should i do, since it's an 02 just change it anyway or wait until it breaks, if it's even the heater core ?

Comment: Do you ever have to top up the engine coolant?  If no one is, then you are not leaking coolant (engine coolant flows through the heater).

Comment: i had to fill it up just yesterday, it was sort of low

Comment: Does your Explorer have zoned HVAC system? Does it have an auto-HVAC system?

Comment: Could be a blocked air conditioning condensation vent causing a drips on the passenger side.

Comment: Is this with only yourself in the car? Your body heat is going to make a significant difference unless there's a lot of airflow in the vehicle.

Comment: it's only me in the vehicle, @paulster it's a zoned HVAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could just as easily be a failed or failing door / window seal, blocked drain hole or be related to the membrane inside the door.  Unless you are noticing your coolant level dropping and having to regularly top up coolant, it's unlikely to be your heater core.

Comment: ill keep a close eye on it, cause it still blows out hot when it warms up so that left me scratching my head